# Programatically prevent search engines to crawl your WordPress Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to programatically stop search engines to crawl a WordPress posts using PHP.

The scenario is, I'm creating a dummy posts along with user registration, I want it to be not searchable otherwise the user edit and save it already. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You are looking for robots.txt, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have not explore yet about the robot txt. What I've tried so far is adding 'ping_status' => 'closed', on the posts. But seems not the solution.

Comment: I don't use Wordpress so I don't really know what that is, but generally if you want to stop a crawler you can do that in a robots.txt file or in a meta in the head. Just code a PHP code that prints the meta if you don't want the page to be indexed.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code snippet in your theme's `functions.php` file or custom plugin file.

```
function ar456_header_metadata() {

    // Seperate Conditional Tag for Pages & single page in other post type

    if( is_page( array( 'page-slug', 'post_id' ) ) or is_single( array( 'page-slug', 'post_id' ) ) ) {  ?>

    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">

    <?php   }

}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'ar456_header_metadata' );
```

In the code, You can see two conditional tag `is_page()` and `is_single()`. The `is_page()` is for Page post type and `is_single()` for all other post type.

Update your Page ID, title or slug in conditional tags & meta tag will be available in these pages.

Example given below.

```
if( is_page( array( 'sample-page', '3' ) ) or is_single( array( 'hello-world', '6' ) ) ) {  ?>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/

Answer (score 1):

If you want *all* posts to be excluded, just add the following to your theme's `<head>` block:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

If you want *some* posts to be excluded, you'll have to include that meta tag conditionally according to whatever rules you want in place.

Comment: I only want specific posts to not crawlable @ceejayoz. But how can I add that meta on dynamically created posts?

Answer (score 0):

Ceejayoz has the perfect answer, but I don't have the reputation to comment directly. You will have to create a template that specifically blocks the robot and then call that template for the posts and pages you want omitting.